# Low values vs Small values

Tags: meaning-in-context, confusable, word-in-context

I would like to describe  the indication of some numerical index, let us say x. I would like to say that   if  x << n  then this indicate positive  impact however x >> n  this indicate negative impact.

In such context, I should say  :

"**Low** values of x indicate positive impact "

or

"**Small** values of x indicate positive impact ".

Which one is correct ? If both, which one is more suitable in my notion ( scientific one)? does it really differ if I use  Low instead of small?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the context of your index? Mathematical? Financial? Social?

Comment: @Peter I stated it is numerical, in fact it is the outcome of a mathematical  formula.

Comment: @Nizar I think Peter's question is about the context of the formula.

Comment: Did you mean to use the "much less than" symbol? (i.e., "<<"). If so, I'm not sure if either statement accurately conveys what you are saying mathematically. It might be better to say, "Values of x which are much smaller than n indicate positive impact."

Answer (score 2):

In my mind there is a subtle difference, although most people would view small and low values of x as meaning the same thing.

To me, 'low' is a comparison to 'normal' or 'high'. If 15,000 units is a typical value, 5,000 units could be a low value, even though it isn't a small value. If a normal score is 2, then a score of -43 would be very low.

A 'small' value to me is a measure of magnitude and indicates a value close to zero. It is somewhat dependent on the range of the data. If we're talking about data that ranges from -1 to 1, -0.0003 might be a small value and -0.75 could be a large value depending on the context. If we're talking about a range of 0 to 100, 20 could be a small value.

Comment: I agree with this. The two are synonyms when speaking casually, but when used more precisely *small* refers to a **small magnitude** (aka absolute value) whereas *low* refers to a **lesser value** (as in less than).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any difference which one you use. They both mean the same thing, and they both sound fine to say. I would probably say small if I was writing it, but if you said low, that would work just as well.

Comment: Nah. In OP's context, [**low** is overwhelmingly more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Small+values+of%2Clow+values+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSmall%20values%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clow%20values%20of%3B%2Cc0)